# Error when importing module from a different folder in the same parent directory

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have the following python package structure:

```
rkstr8/cloud/batch.py
rkstr8/profiling/test.py
```

I'm trying to import a class called `BatchJobListStatusPoller` from batch.py into test.py, but it gives me the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rkstr8'` when I run this import statement in test.py:

`from rkstr8.cloud.batch import BatchJobListStatusPoller`

The rkstr8/ folder, as well as the cloud/ and profiling/ sub-folders all have an `__init__.py`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is rkstr8 the parent folder for your project?

Comment: No, the true parent folder is `aws-sfn-tutorial` --> `aws-sfn-tutorial/rkstr8/....`

Comment: Where is the first file that you run to start the program? Like when you do `python whatever.py`

Comment: I run `python test.py`, which is in `aws-sfn-tutorial/rkstr8/profiling/`

Comment: Yeah the problem there is as mentioned in my answer. It is not really possible as Python only searches through the directory/subdirectories of where you start the program for imports. I will update my answer with your possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because Python only imports modules from directories/subdirectories of wherever you run your program `python test.py`. It also searches for modules in the `sys.path` variable which includes the standard library ones and any installed from pip. I can think of two ways to solve this problem, one is the more standard way and one is more of an unorthodox workaround.

1. The first way would be to have a script directly in the `aws-sfn-tutorial` folder maybe called `start_test.py`. Its sole purpose is to call your `test.py` script upon starting up and pass any command line arguments down.
   This will allow your `test.py` script to then be able to correctly find all the python modules inside the `aws-sfn-tutorial` folder.
2. The second way would be to modify the `sys.path` variable in `test.py` to add in the path to the file you want to import.

   - You can either specify a relative path `../` which moves it one folder up relative to the current path
   - Or you can specify the absolute path to the folder

Example of 2:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../') # Or use the absolute path here instead

# After adding to sys.path import your module
from cloud.batch import BatchJobListStatusPoller
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the 2nd solution :)