# Error importing file in the above directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the fallowing directory tree:

```
foo_project/
├── foo/
│   ├── foo_conversor.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__/
│  
├── foo.py
└── __pycache__/
```

I'm trying to import a class named `Foo` that is inside `foo.py` at `foo_conversor.py`, I've tried a lot of ways but I can't understand how to do this import. Can someone help me? It's any problem with `__init__.py`?

I already tried:

```
from ..foo import Foo
from .. import Foo
from . import Foo
from foo import Foo
```

I've already read a lot fo answers here but none helped me.

Comment: I recently answered a really similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335995/error-when-importing-module-from-a-different-folder-in-the-same-parent-directory/52336239#52336239). It is because Python only looks inside your `/foo` directory for imports. You either have to start the program from a file inside `foo_project` or add the folder to the `sys.path`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: You have both a module `foo` (the file `foo.py`) **and**  a package called `foo` (the directory `foo/` plus the `__init__.py` file). When you `import foo` in any of the variations you tried, the package will be chosen over the module. So you can't import the module when they are named the same.

Comment: You need to either change the name of the module `foo` or change the file name `foo.py`.